# Multicolumn Layout starting at the same height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

[image]

As you can see, the second element is 35px lower than the three other elements. The reason for that is, that each element has a `margin-bottom: 35px;` But why is it appended to the top? If I add `display: inline-block` I can prevent that but then the columns break after the second...
[image]

How can I fix that?

```css
#items {
  display: block;
  column-width: 3rem;
  column-gap: .35rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
#items.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#items .item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 .35rem;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class='show' id='items'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Additionally I only got this problem in Chrome; Firefox and Microsoft Edge work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Display: inline-block, try margin-right: -4px.

This is a known display inline block problem

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: hmm... doesn't change anything

Comment: I guess that's not the case for me, because with `inline-block` it breaks after 2 columns but if I completed two rows it's starting again in the sec column, and so on and so on. I'ts a weird thing, I've never encountered before...

Comment: Additionally I only got this problem in chrome, firefox and edge works fine

Comment: try a vertical-align:top then on your cards